# flutter xcode build failed fatal error: module 'connectivity' not found

Tags: ios, flutter

I am trying to run my little old project. I updating all the plugins and code issues are solved. but now if I run flutter run I get the bellow error

```
        Xcode build done.                                           16.8s
    Failed to build iOS app
    Error output from Xcode build:
    ↳
        ** BUILD FAILED **


    Xcode's output:
    ↳
        /Users/mdzainalabedin/padelmatchv2/ios/Runner/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.m:10
        :9: fatal error: module 'connectivity' not found
        @import connectivity;
        ~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~
        1 error generated.
        note: Using new build system
        note: Planning build
        note: Constructing build description

    Could not build the application for the simulator.
    Error launching application on iPhone 11.
```

Comment: did you get the answer? OR how u solved this issue

Comment: anyone got the answer for this? I guess this is happening just for one package. Its something issue with the iOS build.

Comment: @goutham_mi3 u can see my answer. I have solved it by this command

Answer (score 1):

After wasting so many times, I found only following command in terminal under Project directory folder is worked for me

```
rm ios/Podfile && flutter build ios
```